# ffmpeg libx264 optimization

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

Suppose I have a computer with 16 cores and a large number of videos to convert (say 100)

What is the optimal number of videos to convert at one time?
eg:

16 cores per video, 1 file at a time

8 cores per video, 2 files at a time

4 cores per video, 4 files at a time

4 cores per video, 8 files at a time

Comment: 16 videos, 1 core each. Video quality is slitely better with single thread.

Comment: By better I mean in terms of total time taken

Comment: Have you done some tests? I guess this will be strongly dependent on your I/O performance, too.